# What happens when export names conflict in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, package

I read that in Meteor,

> If your app uses the email package (and only if it uses the email
>   package!) then your app can see Email and you can call Email.send.
>   Most packages have only one export, but some packages might have two
>   or three (for example, a package that provides several classes that
>   work together).

So what happens if your app uses two packages that export a variable named Email?  Which Email does your app get?  Is `Package.a.Email` / `Package.b.Email` the only workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where meteor's namespacing system comes in. Only one of the two packages, typically the one added last will get the global `Email` variable.

The only work around is to use `Package.a` as you've mentioned.

If a package is dependent on another package there shouldn't be an issue if the package in question is referenced correctly with `api.use("xxx")` in the `package.js`

If you use two packages with exports as dependencies for a package you will have to use the `Package.xx` naming convention (note Meteor actually uses this under the hood, it will actually convert your code if you don't use `Package.xx`.

With the global variable, `Email`, you have to be careful as only one of the package will get the global variable.